# In 3D transforms, is scaling on x and y axes equivalent to translation in y?

Tags: ios, core-animation, catransform3d

I was trying to write some code for animations, and started wondering if scaling equally in x and y directions is equivalent to translation in the z axis. Visually, they seem to be the same, but is there any mathematical proof for it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the perspective. For instance if you translate by 2 along the z axis then it could double the size of the object or it could scale it by only a quarter or even smaller. It depends where the "camera" is in the space you are woking in. Scaling by 2 on the x and y will always increase the size to double what it started as.

Mathematically are they the same? Not remotely.

Think about what you are doing in 3D space. If you start with a piece of paper on a table that is 10cm by 10cm.

Now scale it in x and y to 2x.

It is still on the table but now 20x20cm.

Now if you had translated along z axis the paper is still 10x10cm but now hovering above the table.

It looks bigger but only because it is closer and you can see clearly that the same thing has not happened in both cases.

Comment: To be more specific, here's a good link to understanding perspective in OpenGL (which is powering the Core Animation graphics on iOS): http://blog.db-in.com/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/#projections

Comment: Cool, thanks for adding that :-) it's hard to explain what I meant but this seems to cover it :-)